# How to sum total in table vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

There are two rows of data row,

```
<tr v-for="(data, index) in result_estimate.item_tabel" :key="index">
  <td>
    <pre> sub total : {{ambilaja(formatPrice(ambilPrice[index] - (ambilPrice[index] * subtotalRow[index])))}}</pre>
  </td>
<tr>
<div> total : {{this.totals}}</div>
```

The result of the above value is the total of each of each row, here I pass the value into the function ambilaja().

```
 return {
    totals : 0
    },
    computed : (){
         ambilaja: function(){
              return (value) => this.lempar(value)
         },
    }, 
    method : {
       lempar(data){
          console.log(data) 
          result console 
          30002 -> total row index 0
          2003 -> total row index 1
       }
    }
```

How to add up the total ? ex : 30002 + 2003 = this.totals

Comment: From your code `ambilaja` is a computed property. You cannot call it as a function to display the subtotal. You have to seperate your subtotal into a seperate component. Aso you have to use a omputed propery to calcualte your total.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of data is in ambilPrice or subtotalRow but you can just add another method and pass parameters to do calculations.

```js
<tr v-for="(data, index) in result_estimate.item_tabel" :key="index">
  <td>
    <pre> sub total : {{ambilaja(formatPrice(ambilPrice[index] - (ambilPrice[index] * subtotalRow[index])))}}</pre>
  </td>
<tr>
<div> total : {{calTotals(ambilPrice, ambilPrice, subtotalRow)}}</div>
```

Vue Code:

```js
return {
  totals : 0
  },
  method : {
    calTotals(ambilPriceArr, subtotalRow, index) {
      this.totals = this.totals + ambilPriceArr[index] - (ambilPriceArr[index] * subtotalRow[index]);
      return this.totals;
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this issue is to use `computed` property for the total as like below.

```
computed() {
    total: function(){
        let sum = 0;
        this.result_estimate.item_tabel.forEach(item => sum += this.calculatePriceForIndividualRow(item));
        return sum;
    },
},
```

Where `calculatePriceForIndividualRow` is the function that will calculate sum for each row.